# How to configure Jboss EAP7.0 WorkManager in Spring 4.2

Tags: spring, jms, jboss6.x, jca

I am trying to implement the jca based jms in spring with Jboss EAP 7.0 and below are my configuration.

```
<bean class="org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.JmsResourceAdapter" id="jbossResourceAdapter"/>

      <bean id="messageHubTaskExecuter" class="org.springframework.jca.work.WorkManagerTaskExecutor">
 <property name="workManager" value="wm/default"/>
 </bean>


 <bean id="jbossResourceAdapterFactory" class="org.springframework.jca.support.ResourceAdapterFactoryBean">
 <property name="resourceAdapter" ref="jbossResourceAdapter"/>
 <property name="workManager" ref="messageHubTaskExecuter"/>
 </bean>
```

I got the below exception

Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: wm/default -- service jboss.naming.context.java.wm.default
  Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: wm/default -- service jboss.naming.context.java.wm.default"}}

Please let me know how to get the work manager instance in spring 4.2 from Jboss EAP 7.0

Thanks much.